# Oracle SQL Select

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a simple query to compare dates but I am getting an invalid identifier error on the last line of the query.  I get the following error below. Line 15 happens to be the last line of the query.

> Error at Line: 15 Column: 6

```
 Select OP_DATE,
        ID,
        TO_CHAR(DT.OP_DATES.LST_UPDT_TMSP,'DD-MM-YY') as SD 
   From DT.OP_DATES
  Where OP_DATE_IND = 'CMPLTD'
    And OP_DATE_STS = 'M'
    And SD=(SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YY') FROM DUAL)
```

What's wrong with the identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the alias `SD` in the `where` condition.
For example:

```
SQL> select 1 as one
  2  from dual
  3  where one = ( select 1 from dual) ;
where one = ( select 1 from dual)
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "ONE": invalid identifier


SQL> select 1 as one
  2  from dual
  3  where 1 = ( select 1 from dual) ;

       ONE
----------
         1
```

If you want to use the alias in the `where` condition, you need to wrap your query to get a result containing a column with the needed alias:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (
  3          select 1 as one
  4          from dual
  5       )
  6  where one = ( select 1 from dual) ;

       ONE
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: @BreenDeen - To further explain Aleksej's answer: It always help to think about the order of evaluation of clauses in a SQL statement. At least in principle, the FROM clause (including JOIN conditions) and the WHERE clause are evaluated before anything else, while the SELECT clause is evaluated close to the end. The aliases defined in the SELECT clause are not visible to the WHERE clause. Database software creators are free to do other things (such as "read ahead" for any aliases defined later), but I don't know if any do it for this specific operation, and certainly Oracle does not.

Comment: @BreenDeen - As an alternative to the use of subqueries, you could repeat the whole `TO_CHAR(DT.OP_DATES.LST_UPDT_TMSP,'DD-MM-YY')` on the left-hand side of the `WHERE` clause, instead of using the alias. This would avoid the subquery-outer query structure. It is more typing, but it is NOT inefficient; the function appears twice in the query, but it is not actually executed twice. The Oracle engine is smart enough to see it's the same function, so it is computed only once (for each row).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the accepted answer:

```
 Select OP_DATE,
        ID,
        TO_CHAR(DT.OP_DATES.LST_UPDT_TMSP,'DD-MM-YY') as SD 
   From DT.OP_DATES
  Where OP_DATE_IND = 'CMPLTD'
    And OP_DATE_STS = 'M'
    And TO_CHAR(DT.OP_DATES.LST_UPDT_TMSP,'DD-MM-YY') = 
            (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YY') FROM DUAL)
```